# How do I convert tuple of tuples to list in one line (pythonic)?

Tags: python, list, tuples, database-cursor

```
query = 'select mydata from mytable'
cursor.execute(query)
myoutput = cursor.fetchall() 
print myoutput

(('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))
```

Why is it (cursor.fetchall) returning a tuple of tuples instead of a tuple since my query is asking for only one column of data?

What is the best way of converting it to `['aa', 'bb', 'cc']` ?

I can do something like this :

```
mylist = []
myoutput = list(myoutput)
for each in myoutput:
   mylist.append(each[0])
```

I am sure this isn't the best way of doing it. Please enlighten me!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This works as well:

```
>>> tu = (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.chain(*tu))
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

**Edit** `Could you please comment on the cost tradeoff? (for loop and itertools)`

Itertools is significantly faster:

```
>>> t = timeit.Timer(stmt="itertools.chain(*(('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',)))")
>>> print t.timeit()
0.341422080994
>>> t = timeit.Timer(stmt="[a[0] for a in (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))]")
>>> print t.timeit()
0.575773954391
```

**Edit 2** `Could you pl explain itertools.chain(*)`

That `*` unpacks the sequence into positional arguments, in this case a nested tuple of tuples.

Example:

```
>>> def f(*args):
...    print "len args:",len(args)
...    for a in args:
...       print a
... 
>>> tu = (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))
>>> f(tu)
len args: 1
(('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))
>>> f(*tu)
len args: 3
('aa',)
('bb',)
('cc',)
```

Another example:

```
>>> f('abcde')
len args: 1
abcde
>>> f(*'abcde')
len args: 5
a
b
c
d
e
```

See [the documents on unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html#arbitrary-argument-lists).

Comment: Could you please comment on the cost tradeoff? (for loop and itertools)

Comment: This is what I am looking for, thank you! Could you pl explain itertools.chain(*)

Comment: @ThinkCode: The star operator unpacks a sequence, in this case the list of tuples. It is not unique to `itertools`.

Answer (score 4):

You could do

```
>>> tup = (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))
>>> lst = [a[0] for a in tup]
>>> lst
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Comment: Thank you. I am trying to see if I can do away with the 'for' loop.

Comment: This code doesn't use a for loop - it uses a list comprehension (although obviously 'under the hood' it is converted into something like a for loop, but one doesn't expect to do something to every element of a list without using some kind of loop, even if its disguised as a list comprehension or some kind of higher order function...)

Answer (score 2):

What you are doing is correct but more concise and may be better performing could be

```
>>> [item for item, in (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',)) ]
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

or if you hate `for` keyword, you can use map

```
>>> map(lambda a:a[0], (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',)) )
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

and here is another way

```
>>> reduce(lambda a, b:a+b, (('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',)) )
('aa', 'bb', 'cc')
```

though IMO list comprehension is most readable

Comment: A list comprehension is not a for loop.

Answer (score 2):

> Why is `cursor.fetchall()` returning a tuple of tuples instead of a tuple since my query is asking for only one column of data?

The outer tuple is the complete result; each inner tuple represents one record in that result; because you asked for only one field, each inner tuple has only one element.

> What is the best way of converting it to ['aa', 'bb', 'cc'] ?

There are several ways, and which is 'best' depends on what you are doing...

Simple list comprehension:

```
mylist = [each[0] for each in myoutput]
```

Simple generator (saves on memory usage):

```
mygen = (each[0] for each in myoutput)
for result in mygen:
    print result
```

If you just need to process the items in `myoutput`, you could also do

```
for each, in myoutput:
    print each
```

If you have profiled your code and discovered that this is a bottleneck, then you can go for less readable but faster:

```
import itertools
mylist = list(itertools.chain(*myoutput))
```

or, again if you just need to process it:

```
import itertools
for result in itertools.chain(*myoutput):
    print result
```

Answer (score 1):

This works:

```
>>> tups=(('aa',), ('bb',), ('cc',))
>>> list(*(zip(*tups)))
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Explanation:

```
1) *tups unpacks the nested tuples  ('aa'),('bb'),('cc')
2) zip produces a list of a single tuple with all the elements: [('aa','bb','cc')]
3) * unpacks that  into  'aa', 'bb', 'cc'
4) creates a list from that unpacking.
```

You could also do:

```
>>> list(zip(*tups)[0])
['aa', 'bb', 'cc']
```

Comment: I like it! Could you please explain the list(*(zip(*tups))) part? That way I can remember it easily.

Comment: *tups and zip's behavior in this case is something new to me. It is clean and elegant too. I am hoping this is performance-efficient too. Thank you!

Comment: I have Python 2.6.6 on my dev machine and >>> tups=(('aa,','bb,','cc,'))
>>> list(*(zip(*tups)))
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: list() takes at most 1 argument (3 given) gives me an error. list(zip(*tups)[0]) works though!

Answer (score 0):

Do a list comprehension like this:

```
mylist = [ x[0] for x in myoutput ]
```