# How to convert a tuple of tuples to a list of lists?

Tags: python, list, tuples

I would like to convert the tuple of tuples into a list of lists.

I don't want to flatten it, unlike [these](https://stackoverflow.com/q/20637970/1801588) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8171751/1801588), and I don't want to make it a numpy array like [in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19756242/1801588).

My only idea so far is to iterate the tuples with for loops and copy the values, but there must be something cleaner and more pythonic.

Comment: You can try simply map(list, a)

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Is this what you want? -

```
In [17]: a = ((1,2,3),(4,5,6),(7,8,9))

In [18]: b = [list(x) for x in a]

In [19]: b
Out[19]: [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]
```

This is called list comprehension, and when you do `list(x)` where x is an iterable (which also includes tuples) it converts it into a list of same elements.

Comment: This works on python interpreter, but not in the script ...wierd. I get the error in the script as: TypeError: list() takes no arguments (1 given)

Comment: Are you sure in your script, you do not have a function like - `def list():` ?

Comment: Anand S Kumar you just solved my problem! Thx a lot!... I had another list method in my flask views.py